# Passing information to a controller through params (not saving it to the db). How to put it inside a hash like the users params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have information that is passed to a controller method but isn't saved to the DB. I want to access this information, that is passed to the controller method as a whole hash, but it is all individual data as you will see below.

Here is the params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0O7pbNNrddHCyPL9B/avUUD85574rFBfS57h+aWKK/mBakPSn5iHJKHhPmvuJVfyWxjBsAQn2kagwkTOALEKRg==", "page"=>{"content_top"=>"", "content_bottom"=>""}, "header1"=>"iijijij", "column1"=>"ijijijij", "header2"=>"", "column2"=>"", "header3"=>"", "column3"=>"", "header4"=>"", "column4"=>"", "commit"=>"Save", "guide_id"=>"dungeon-boss", "category_id"=>"heroes", "id"=>"link-skill"}
```

As you can see there is a `page` hash and after, it is `header1` `column1` `header2` `column2`... and so on. With the `header1` info, I'm trying to put it inside a params hash like the `page` hash has for the values passed in it. So it's like `"table" =>{"header1"=>"iijijij", "column1"=>"ijijijij", "header2"=>"", "column2"=>"", "header3"=>"", "column3"=>"", "header4"=>"", "column4"=>""}`

I'm sure there is something I need to add to the form so it know to group them like this. Here is the form I currently have

```
<%  if (current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?) %>
   <%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

       <%= f.label :content_top, "Top Content" %>
       <%= f.text_area :content_top, :class => 'editor' %>

       <%= f.label :content_bottom, "Bottom Content" %>    
       <%= f.text_area :content_bottom, :class => 'editor' %>

     <!-- to be in one hash when passed -->

       <%= text_field_tag :header1 %>    
       <%= text_field_tag :column1 %>

       <%= text_field_tag :header2 %>    
       <%= text_field_tag :column2 %>

       <%= text_field_tag :header3 %>    
       <%= text_field_tag :column3 %>

       <%= text_field_tag :header4 %>    
       <%= text_field_tag :column4 %>

     <!-- end -->

       <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

    <% end %>
```

I cant find what I need to add to make the `text_field_tag` data all be in one hash when passed.(the `text_field_tag` is purposely not being saved to the DB on form submit, it just needs to be passed to the method and grouped inside a hash)

Answer (score 1):

how about using `fields_for` like this

```
<%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :content_top, "Top Content" %>
   <%= f.text_area :content_top, :class => 'editor' %>

   <%= f.label :content_bottom, "Bottom Content" %>    
   <%= f.text_area :content_bottom, :class => 'editor' %>

 <!-- to be in one hash when passed -->
   <%= f.fields_for :table do |t| %>

     <%= t.text_field_tag :header1 %>    
     <%= t.text_field_tag :column1 %>

     <%= t.text_field_tag :header2 %>    
     <%= t.text_field_tag :column2 %>

     <%= t.text_field_tag :header3 %>    
     <%= t.text_field_tag :column3 %>

     <%= t.text_field_tag :header4 %>    
     <%= t.text_field_tag :column4 %>
   <% end %>

 <!-- end -->

   <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the array way if you want to send the data that doesn't belong to the model, in `params` hash inside `page` key. Here's how:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'page[header1]' %>
```

Not only this, if you would like to use another key, you can use that as well like `<%= text_field_tag 'custom_key[header1]' %>`

Comment: What if I want to send it inside another key? would `<%= text_field_tag 'table[header1]' %>` on each of these fields tag put them inside a `table` hash?